# Jersey 2.x dynamic binding

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0, hk2

Is there any way to provide a dynamic binding at runtime? AbstractBinder allows you to bind a factory but the class type has to be known at compile time.

Something to the effect of:

```
public class MyDynamicBinder implements DynamicBinder {
    @Override
    public boolean canBind(Class<?> someContract) {
        return iCanBindThis(someContract);
    }

    @Override
    public Object bind(Class<?> someContract) {
        return getMyInstance(someContract);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

hk2 is an extremely dynamic injection container.  Unlike guice and CDI it can add services to its [ServiceLocator](https://hk2.java.net/2.5.0-b28/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/api/ServiceLocator.html) at any time (if you have appropriate privilege).  With the [ServiceLocator](https://hk2.java.net/2.5.0-b28/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/api/ServiceLocator.html) (which is a service available anywhere you have any other hk2 service) then you can use the methods in [ServiceLocatorUtilities](https://hk2.java.net/2.5.0-b28/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/utilities/ServiceLocatorUtilities.html) like addClasses or addOneDescriptor in order to add whatever services you need at any time at all.  You can also remove services at any time, but few people ever do that (unless you are writing a dynamic container of your own)